# 3D gaming WYSIWYGs for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm not a graphics or game designer but would like to build more interactivity into my iPhone apps and eventually start developing gaming apps.  Tools such as Blender seem for out into the future for anything I'll produce useful from them.  I need something similar to a FrontPage for game developers.  For 300 bucks, Torgue for the iPhone seems like a nice all in one package: http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3D.  Has anyone used this or something similar and can comment about how good it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the coolest end-to-end solutions that I've seen to date is [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/), which now allows you to publish your game directly as an [iPhone application](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing).  It's not exactly cheap, but you can get an indie license for $598. There's good support and plenty of community examples and stuff to get you going.

Comment: Unity3D looks exactly like the thing I need.  Thanks.

Comment: To be specific, the Indie license is $199 + iPhone Publishing Basic for it is $399. The Basic version will display a Unity splash screen on start up. That's wonky. Are there any games in the App Store that do this because they were built with the Basic version?

Comment: I hadn't realised about the splash screen, the Advanced iPhone license is pretty expensive at $1499 considering you need to already have the Unity pro license which also costs $1499. Like I said, it's not exactly cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Torque and Blender aren't really comparable: Torque is primarily a game engine and Blender is primarily a 3D modelling application. You'd use the latter to create content for the former.